# Overlay emitting Observable in RxJs timer

Tags: angular, rxjs

## Preface

The angular application that I'm currently developing requests a certain state from the underlaying API every 10 seconds. Depending on what the state is users should be displayed a series of overlays indicating steps they need to perform in order to make the system run smoothly. The problem I'm about to describe is mainly an rxjs related issue. But let me introduce you smoothly. Please note that the whole system is way more complex and that I'm doing my best to provide all the necessary information without actually disclosing parts of my actual code.

### The Update

I have a service which sends a request every 10 seconds realized with an rx timer. The timer itself is started using the function below. Each cycle a HTTP request is sent to the server requesting the current systems state. The result gets passed to a publicly available BehaviorSubject so that other components can subscribe on it to receive the values and act according to those.

```
onUpdateReceived = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

startContinuousUpdate(): void {
    this.updateSubscription = this.timerSub = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        mergeMap(cycle => this.http.get("some url")
    ).subscribe((result: any) => {
        this.onUpdateReceived.next(result);
    })
}
```

## Overlay excursus

As already mentioned in the preface of this post. One or more connected overlays should be triggered in a specific component depending on the just received state.

Before I can explain the desired behavior here's a quick excursus to how the overlay itself is working. The overlay is implemented using the angular CDK Overlay feature.
My OverlayService gets called to open an overlay based on some config and a Component to render in the main Overlay Component using Component portals.

```
open(config): OverlayRef {
    // do something with the config
    const ref = new OverlayRef(...);
    const injector = createInjector(ref, this.injector);
    ref.attach(new ComponentPortal(OverlayComponent, null, injector));
    return ref;
}

createInjector(ref: OverlayRef, i: Injector) {
    const tokens = new WeakMap([[OverlayRef, ref]]);
    return new PortalInjector(i, tokens);
}
```

The templated OverlayRef class holds a Subject that, since its injected to the final component to be rendered in the portal, gets emitted once the user closes the overlay with a value.

Generally this structure has proven to be well integrable into rx-based workflows.
However there seems to be a general problem with this method and the usage of a timer.

## Minimal Example of the actual problem

The actual issue occurs within the subscriton to the aforementioned BehaviorSubject that gets a new value every 10 seconds.

`some-specific.compoenent.ts`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.updateService.onUpdateReceived.pipe(
         switchMap(data => {

             if(this.overlaysOpen)
                 return of(null);

             return this.overlay.open(OverlayAConfig).afterClosed$.pipe(
                 mergeMap( choice => {
                     if(choice)
                         return this.overlay.open(YetAnotherConfig1).afterClosed$;
                         this.overlaysOpen = true;
                     else
                         return this.overlay.open(YetAnotherConfig2).afterClosed$;
                         this.overlaysOpen = true;
                 })
             }) 
     ).subscribe(result => {
         // do something with the final results being either null or a value
         doSomething(result);
         if(conditions_indicating_that_the_overlays_are_closed)
             this.overlaysOpen = false;
     })
}
```

This is the most minimal representation of the actual code.

## Expectation vs. Reality (of some sorts)

### What the code is supposed to do:

If there is any open overlay: simply return null and therefor skip.
If no overlay is open: Open the first overlay, wait for users to decide for an option. With respect to the choice open a different overlay, wait for the users input again. Continue to do so as long as the application is running. Within the subscribe block: handle the input.

### What the code does:

Once an overlay was opened users read the information and decide for the next step. **If**, and that's the issue right here, while the first overlay is open new values are being requested whatever choice users make will be 'ignored'. That happens (I think) because the subscription gets overwritten (or deleted, cancelled name it as you like) and there is no information as to how to continue now because the code itself has just started over.

I've been playing around with switchMap (as in the example) vs mergeMap but neither made any difference. I could (and I did) trigger the overlay code within the final subscription (which obviously works) but this is an anti pattern. Furthermore, since the structure now has to be extended this is simply not suitable anymore. Not even mentioning that its an rx anti pattern.

So In case anyone understood my problem:
Is there any way to trigger this chain of events without having to kill the timer and restart it after users have made their choices (which is not really an option here since the requested state cannot be terminated --> other things that still need to be handled)

In case no-one understands it:
I'm doomed :D But I can't seem to find a better way of describing the issue.
I might be able to create a minimum working example faking all of the above mentioned dependencies but because the sprint only has limited time left I don't really see it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few strange things in what you've given us.

---

## 1

At a high level, an api polling system that doesn't just blindly run every 10 seconds would likely serve you well. There are times you want to be polling the API endpoint and times you'd rather not. A system that account for that would be a bit more robust.

---

## 2

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
mergeMap( choice => {
  if(choice)
     this.overlay.open(YetAnotherConfig1).afterClosed$;
     this.overlaysOpen = true;
  else
    this.overlay.open(YetAnotherConfig2).afterClosed$;
    this.overlaysOpen = true;
})
```

this is effectively `mergeMap(a -> undefined)`

which I would expect to give the following error:

> Error:
> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

---

## 3

Perhaps a quick fix:

- Use `exhaustMap` rather than `switchMap`. `exhaustMap` will ignore source emissions while an inner observable is still active. This will stop the user's choices being overwritten, but you'll be dropping updates from the API endpoint while the user makes choices.
- Use `concatMap` rather than `switchMap`. `concatMap` will buffer source emissions while an inner observable is still active. This will stop the user's choices being overwritten, but if the user takes 1 minute to complete an overlay, the system will have to process 6 updates from the API endpoint at once. So you'll need a means to handle this without destroying the user experience.

Comment: wrt: 2. Sorry for that, I forgot the return statement and I added it. I was trying to reconstruct a lightweight version of my code and I simply overlooked that one.

Comment: Thanks for the `exhaustMap` hint though. The problem was mainly within the switch map statement which worked all along. Simply an uncaught error in one of the inner functions caused the whole cycle to collapse